# error: 'gint' has not been declared

Tags: android, gstreamer

I am trying to build a Gstreamer plugin(a surface texture sink) in android. I got this error along with several others:

```
"error: 'gint' has not been declared".
```

I did source build/envsetup.sh and then went into the sink directory and did "mm". Then I got the above error.

I believe I should include "gst.h" and "glib.h". But when I add these include lines, I get an error saying that these files cannot be located. So, I think that the path to these header files need to be set correctly. But I don't know how or where to set this path.

Should Android.mk be modified in some way ?

Kindly help 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

gint is declared in glib.h on all systems I have seen. Do you have glib installed?

Comment: yeah, I know where to find the file "glib.h". But I dont know how to include it in the path in android.

Comment: ok, I have not tried to use glib on android, but on other systems you specify the path to glib.h with -I /path/to/glib. If pkg-config is installed the correct -I flags can be taken from the command: pkg-config --cflags glib-2.0 (but I don't know if this works on android).

Comment: Thanks anyway Albert :) appreciate it :)